# N needed for probability > .001 of two people being a match at six genetic markers?

Tags: probability, statistics

If for each marker there is a 1/9 chance that any two people are a match, how large would the sample need to be for the probability to exceed .001 that two people are a match at six markers?

Comment: Is marker matching independent? It appears that is an assumption, but not stated. What problem are you having with this?

Comment: There are some unstated assumptions here that need to be stated explicitly, otherwise the question makes no sense.  You might be assuming that the events "person $a$ matches person $b$ at marker $c$" are all independent with probability $1/9$.  However, I think this
isn't really tenable, because matching should be a transitive relation: if Abe matches Beth at a certain marker, and Beth matches Carol at that same marker, then shouldn't Abe match Carol at that marker?

Comment: I posted an answer that assumes matching for different markers is independent.

Comment: @RobertIsrael : To be realistic, the events that two persons match and marker $c$ and that they match at marker $d$ may not be at all independent, and that's the big issue, but the transitivity relation you mention doesn't seem like a big obstacle to solution at all.

Comment: In R: `p = (1/9)^6;  1 - dbinom(0, 550, p)` returns
$ 0.001034388.$

Comment: @BruceET how did you derive the arguments for dbinom?

Comment: @BruceET Is there any way to arrive at the number of trials without guessing or using an arbitrary starting value?

Comment: Confused about reasonable assumptions for this situation. Deleting previous comments.

Answer (score 1):

This is the celebrated "birthday problem": How many people must be randomly chosen from a population in order that the probability is at least $1/2$ that some pair among them have the same birthday (assuming, not so realistically, that all $365$ dates are equally probable and that we exclude those born on the 29th of February for the sake of simplicity)?

I'm construing the question as referring to the probability that somewhere among the sample there are two that match.

This is one of those problems most easily solved by asking what is the probability that the event in question does NOT happen.

The probability that two persons match at six markers is $1/9^6.$ The probability that they don't is $1 - (1/9^6).$ Among $N$ persons, the probability that no two match is
\begin{align}
& \Pr(\text{2nd doesn't match 1st}) \\[8pt]
{} \times {} & \Pr(\text{3rd doesn't match first 2} \\
& \qquad\qquad\text{given that the first 2 don't match}) \\[8pt]
{} \times {} & \Pr(\text{4th doesn't match first 3} \\
& \qquad \text{given that no two among the first 3 match}) \\[8pt]
{} \times {} & \cdots\cdots \\[10pt]
= {} & \left(1 - \tfrac 1 {9^6} \right) \times\left( 1 - \tfrac 2 {9^6} \right) \times \left( 1 - \tfrac 3 {9^6} \right) \times\cdots\times\left( 1 - \tfrac {N-1} {9^6} \right).
\end{align}
One way to proceed from here is brute-force computation: compute this for successive values of $N$ until it is no more than $1-0.001.$

I think there may also be an intelligent to do go on from there; maybe I'll see if I can find it.

(Here I assumed that the events that you and I match at different markers are nine **independent** events. Whether they are independent is something you haven't said anything about.)

Comment: Yes, the implicit assumption I am making is that they are independent.

Comment: What would be a good way to demonstrate this in R?

Comment: If $m= 9^6$, the probability of no match in your model is $m! m^{-N}/(m-N)!$.  For fixed $N$, as $m \to \infty$ this is asymptotically $1 - N(N-1)/(2m) + O(1/m^2)$.  Solving $ N(N-1)/(2 \cdot 9^6) = 1/1000$ gives approximately $N= 33.1$.  And indeed for $N=33$ the probability of at least one match is slightly less than $1/1000$, while for $N=34$ it is slightly greater.

Comment: @BruceET You want $9^6$, not $6^9$.

Comment: Sorry for typo: `k = 1:33;  1 - prod(1-k/9^6)` returns
$0.001055086.$

Answer (score 1):

An approximation seems appropriate here.

Assuming independence of matching different markers, the probability that any two people match six markers is $(1/9)^6$.  If there are $n$ people in the sample, there are $\binom{n}{2}$ pairs.  If we define a success as two people matching six markers, then the expected number of successes is
$$\lambda = \binom{n}{2} \left( \frac{1}{9} \right)^6$$
The events that different pairs of people match on all six markers are *not* independent, so the total number of successes does not have a Binomial distribution.  But the events are "approximately" independent, so as an approximation we might assume that the total number of matches has a Binomial distribution.  And for small probabilities the Binomial distribution is approximately Poisson, so we might as well go all the way and assume the total number of matches is Poisson with parameter $\lambda$.  With that assumption, if $X$ is the total number of successes then
$$P(X \ge 1) = 1- P(X=0) = 1-e^{-\lambda}$$
We want $P(X \ge 1) \ge 0.001$, which is equivalent to $P(X=0) \le 0.999)$.  So we have the equivalent inequalities
$$e^{-\lambda} \le 0.999$$
$$\lambda \ge -\ln(0.999)$$
$$\binom{n}{2} \left( \frac{1}{9} \right)^6 \ge -\ln(0.999)$$
Either by trial and error or by solving a quadratic equation, we find that the least $n$ that satisfies the final inequality is $n= 34$, which results in $P(X \ge 1) \approx 0.0011$.